# ¿Cómo convertir de fecha mm/dd/yyyy a dd/mm/yyyy en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, .net

Buen día quiero convertir mi fecha inicio y fecha fin en formato `dd/mm/yyyy`, por que parece ser que JavaScript las obtiene como `mm/dd/yyyy`, un ejemplo tengo esta fecha 07/01/2021, el 07 me lo toma como mm, cuando este debería ser el dd y el 01 debería ser mm, la verdad ya implemente varios métodos, pero no me funciona, espero puedan ayudarme de favor, anexo código con lo que tengo, estás fechas están dentro de una tabla tipo *Grid View*, yo tengo un array para las columnas y celdas.

Espero puedan apoyarme de favor.

```
$("#ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").on("click", "tr td a[class='green'] i[class='ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130']", function (e) {
        selectedId = $(this).attr("data-id");

        var ArrayID = selectedId.split(" ");
        var Mes = ArrayID[0];
        var RowIndex = ArrayID[1];

        var fechaInicio = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[1].innerText);
        var fechaFin = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[2].innerText);

        var dd = fechaInicio.getDate();
        var mm = fechaInicio.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = fechaInicio.getFullYear();
        
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
        }

        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
        }

        var fechaInicio = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
        document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").valueOf = fechaInicio;
```

El código es *JavaScript* y trabajo con *.Net*

Lo que tengo actualmente es esto con lo que me proporcionaste:

```
const fechaInicio = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[1].innerText);

    function print(fechaInicio ) {
    console.log(`La fecha de hoy es: ${fechaInicio }`);  
    }

 ////Formato que no quiero, mm/dd/yyy
    print(fechaInicio.toDateString('en-US'));

    print(fechaInicio.toDateString('en-GB'));
```

Saludos.

Comment: Si no quieres reinventar la rueda con temas de fechas en JavaScript échale un vistazo a moment.js: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Dayjs es moment pero mejor y mas rapido, lo hace la misma gente :D es mejor pasarse a Day.js.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo más fácil sería usar [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toLocaleString) con un formato de una región que utilice dd/mm/yyyy, como algún país Europeo. Te hago un ejemplo con Gran Bretaña:

```js
const fecha = new Date();
/*equivalente a:
 *var fechaInicio = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[1].innerText);
 */

function print(stringFecha) {
  console.log(`La fecha de hoy es: ${stringFecha}`);
}

//Formato gringo que no quieres, mm/dd/yyy
print(fecha.toLocaleString('en-US'));

//Formato de Gran bretaña, que te sirve, dd/mm/yyy
print(fecha.toLocaleString('en-GB'));

//Si solo quieres la fecha:
print(fecha.toLocaleString('en-GB').split(",")[0]);
```

### UPDATE

Veo en los comentarios que la fecha te sigue quedando al revés, el formato de GB con el `localeString()` siempre va adar al fecha como `dd/mm/yyyy`, si aún así sigue saliendo al revés es porque al parsear la fecha en el constructor del objeto `Date`, es decir, cuando haces `fechaInicio = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[1].innerText);` se está pasando al revés, lo cual tiene sentido porque el constructor de `Date` acepta las horas en formato gringo, algo como `new Date("02/01/2021)` se convertiría en primero de Febrero.

¿Podrías incluir en tu pregunta el resultado de un `console.log` de fechaInicio? Algo así:

```
fechaInicio = new Date(document.getElementById("ConsultaFechasPagoPensiones").rows[RowIndex].cells[1].innerText);
console.log(fechaInicio);
```

Esto con el fin de conocer que es lo que estás pasando al construtor `Date`.

Comment: FranAcuna, tu formato de Gran Bretaña esta bién, pero mi fecha de ejemplo es 07/01/2021, y tu formato de Gran Bretaña me la pone así 01/07/2021, y no debería de ser así debería ser como 07/01/2021, por que así tengo mis fechas el 07 debe ser mi Dia y 01 debe ser mi mes, osea no esta mal el formato que das solo que me invierte la fecha, como hago para dejarla como 07/01/2021 tomando 07 como día, en ese formato.

Comment: Te respondí en la respuesta

Comment: Hola Fran sigue saliendo igual.

Comment: Sí, yo sé, te estoy diciendo que si puedes incluir en tu pregunta el resultado del `console.log()`. ¿Leíste la respuesta?

Comment: Si la lei y es lo mismo

Comment: No te estoy dando una solución, estoy pidiéndote que por favor edites tu pregunta con un ejemplo del valor que estás ingresando en el constructor de `Date`, para poder darte una solución porque el problema va por ahí... Yo no tengo telepatía y no se que es lo que estás ingresando al constructor y con tu ejemplo es **imposible** saberlo... Si editas la pregunta con eso sería fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Ya edite mu pregunta Fran

Comment: No necesito el código, eso lo puedo hacer yo, necesito saber qué es lo que imprime el `console.log()`. O una foto de las celdas, eso es todo lo que necesito.